# Pyspark: Finding the intersection of two dataframes returns only one column with values

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark

I have one data frame with these values - Store ID, Item Available or not (0 or 1) and percentage of availability.

```
Store ID    Item_1_Available    Percent Available
100                 0               0
200                 1               0.2
300                 0               0
400                 1               0.9
```

There is one more data frame it is for a different Item and the availability indicators. There might be store ID's from the first table too which is present here - same store selling different items

```
Store ID    Item_2_Available    Percent Available
400                 1             0.8
600                 1             0.7
700                 0             0
100                 1             0.5
```

I am trying to get one final table (of 50 more items with the structure below).

```
Store ID    Item_1_Available    Percent Available   Item_2_Available    Percent Available
100                 0           0                     1                 0.5
200                 1           0.2                   0                 0
300                 0           0                     0                 0
400                 1           0.9                   1                 0.8
600                 0           0                     1                 0.7
700                 0           0                     0                 0
```

I tried to do a intersect using spark to get the final table so that I can find stores which have both Item 1 and 2.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def intersect(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.intersect, dfs)

final_table = intersect(df1, df2)
```

But it returns only one column from the first table as output.

```
Store ID    Item_1_Available
100         1
200         0
300         0
400         1
```

Is there a way to just do a join on both the tables to get the final table?

Comment: Based on which column you're comparing two dataframe ?

Comment: @Yukeshkumar It should be based on the Store ID

Comment: what you need is a `full_outer` join on `Store ID` field.

Comment: @samkart No, full_outer join is going to create duplicate columns in the final table.

Comment: Then, in final dataframe you can use dropDuplicates().

Comment: a full join won't create duplicate columns if you use `coalesce()` like `coalesce('col_a_from_tab1', 'col_a_from_tab2')`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

storeDF1 = spark.read.csv("store1.txt",header="True")
storeDF2 = spark.read.csv("store2.txt",header="True")

storeDF1.join(storeDF2,on="Store ID",how="full").show(truncate=False)

+--------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+--- 
---------------------+
|Store ID|Item_1_Available|Percent Available item 
1|Item_2_Available|Percent Available item 2|
+--------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+--- 
---------------------+
|700     |null            |null                    |0               |0                       
|
|200     | 1              |0.2                     |null            
|null                    |
|300     | 0              |0                       |null            
|null                    |
|100     | 0              |0                       |1               |0.5                     
|
|600     |null            |null                    |1               |0.7                     
|
|400     | 1              |0.9                     |1               |0.8                     
|
+--------+----------------+------------------------+----------------+--- 
---------------------+
```

Used different name for percent available column in order to avoid column ambiguous error if you want to perform operation over that column.

Comment: It is not just the common store ID's that I need to display. The final table should have all the Store ID's with the other columns and values can be zero when there is no value in that column (like the final table I posted in the question)